# empty component after react render

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to render a react component inside a html page. what i did so far is implementing react like this

```
var component =  React.createClass({
render: function(){
var testStyle = { fontSize: '18px', marginRight: '20px'};
return (
  <div>

    <h1>Hello React</h1>
    <div><ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
    </ul></div>
  </div>

  )

  }
  });

 ReactDOM.render(< component/>,
 document.getElementById('content')
 );
```

and in the HTML page i have this

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

when i inspect the HTMl page i find that inside the div i have an empty component like this

```
<component data-reactroot=""></component>
```

what am i doing wrong here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A React component must always start with a capital letter, otherwise React interprets it as a simple HTML element.

> [Capitalized types indicate that the JSX tag is referring to a React component.](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#specifying-the-react-element-type)

---

That being said, define

`const Component = React.createClass...`

and then render like

```
ReactDOM.render(<Component />, 
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer; that's what was missing it's now working great, i've been following a tutorial in Youtube and i guess i didn't notice the Capitalized letter

Comment: Im glad it worked. Please accept the answer it really helps me out - the check mark next to the answer :-)